# Xcode 6.4 / LLDB: How to interact with private class members of UIKit objects revealed in object explorer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uikit, lldb

Often when debugging (and out of curiosity) I expand the object explorer at left and see lots of '_' prefixed fields of a UIKit object, say, `UINavigationBar`, as pictured below.

There's lots of fields like `_titleView` that must be deeply private, not even revealed when jumping to the class definition.

Furthermore the object explorer reveals classes like `UINavigationItemView` which the documentation doesn't even have, and which the lldb prompt denies knowing about.

(This is probably part of the issue: UINavigationItem.h has `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
@interface UINavigationItemView : UIView { ... }`)

Again mostly out of curiosity but would like to shed light on the matter.[image: Debugger output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those instances variables come from Objective-C runtime type information

The Objective-C runtime stores information about the iVars of classes, in the form of names and type encodings (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html)

The debugger knows how to poke at that runtime information, and produce a representation of the internal guts of your object from that information

That information is, however, not used by the language when making Objective-C types available to your Swift code

Part of the story is that this runtime information may be incorrect or incomplete, which would of course be solvable by blacklisting the erroneous cases (NSURL comes to mind as a typical example, and there are a few more caveats)

However, in general, the iVar information from the runtime is implementation detail and definitely not part of the public interface of a type. It is useful to see in the debugger, but it is not exposed as part of the type's interface in Swift. That explains the fact that, while you can see the data in the variables view, you can't actually evaluate expressions involving it

Comment: Anyway to take the memory address revealed by that info, though, and force the debugger to do a dump as if it were an exposed object? Something like this from gdb: `print (char *)0x70deadbeef`?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. If your ivar is of an "obj-c object type" it will have a pointer value directly, which is exposed to you in the variables view. So you can just use it directly. For instance, in your screenshot, you would say expr (char*)0x7f9e88ca5df0

Comment: Nope. `(lldb) expr (char *)0x7fd1528236d0`
`error: <EXPR>:1:8: error: expected expression after operator`
`(char *)0x7fd1528236d0
       ^`
`<EXPR>:1:9: error: consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'`
`(char *)0x7fd1528236d0`
        ^
        ;

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, that's because you are in Swift code, so we are going to try and parse your expression in swift. try expr -l objc++ -- (char *)0x7fd1528236d0